# Add or change time in datetime object

Tags: python

I have multiple datetime objects, for example:

```
>>a
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0)
```

I want to keep date unchanged and alter time to zeros (three digits in time):

```
>>b
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Probably simple but i can't figure it out

**EDIT:**
For some reason a zero for seconds doesnt work. It does not matter, it works with a 1:

```
>>a
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>b = datetime.datetime.combine(a.date(), datetime.time(0,0,0))
>>b
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>b = datetime.datetime.combine(a.date(), datetime.time(0,0,1))
>>b
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I don't get it: `datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0)==datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Isn't it the same two or three zeros in datatime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit fiddly, but you can use `combine`:

```
b = datetime.datetime.combine(a.date(), datetime.time(0,0,0))
```

Comment: For some reason the last zero in the time is left out. But when i use 1,1,1 in time i get all Three ones.

Comment: Can you explain why you care about the third zero?

Comment: Im trying to create a pandas dataframe from a table but when importing the datetimes the type is changed to Object. Another date field which have format datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 21, 9, 7, 38) is not changed to Object. So im trying to figure out why

Comment: two things:
(1) you can use datetime.time.min instead of time(0,0,0)
(2) in this case id date a had a timezone info (timezone aware), b date will not have  it - then this may not be a desired solution

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime
date_with_zeros = datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 1, 0, 0).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

Just use replace.

Comment: do not forget about microsecond...

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0)` and `datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)` create the same datetime objects. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime for details.

If you have non-zero hours, minutes or seconds you can use `replace` to make them zero:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 1, 3, 15, 49)
dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```